# reactMUI badge color customization

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How to override the custom `primary` and `secondary` color of `badges` while using React MUI v5

i tried using `createTheme` approach

```
const Theme= createTheme({
  palette: {
    type: 'dark',
    primary: {
      main: '#56b53f',
    },
    secondary: {
      main: '#007ef5',
    },
    text: {
      primary: '#ffffff',
    },
    divider: 'rgba(0,0,0,0.12)',
  },
    
});
```

there is a variable vote whose value is between 0 and 10 and i want to switch color of badge according to the value of vote like this

```
<Badge theme={Theme} color={vote > 8 ? "primary" : "secondary"}/>
```

i also tried direct colors but that also didnt work

```
<Badge theme={Theme} color={vote > 8 ? "green" : "blue"}/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your main app with the `ThemeProvider` in the _app.js and pass the theme prop as shown below.

```
import { ThemeProvider } from '@mui/material'
import theme from '../theme'

function MyApp({ Component, pageProps }) {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Component {...pageProps} />
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

export default MyApp
```